# video connectivity for ARDRONE

Tags: opencv, ros, ar.drone

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('tcp://192.168.1.1:5555')
running = True
while running:
    # get current frame of video
    running, frame = cam.read()
    if running:
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27: 
            # escape key pressed
            running = False
    else:
        # error reading frame
        print 'error reading video feed'
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The above code doesn't work for video stream in ARDRONE 2.0

Can somebody provide a fix or any alternate solution to get the video stream of ARDRONE when it is flying ?

Comment: @hoju : Please look into this.

Comment: @Salman S :have you achieved it ?? I am trying to get the video stream or images from ARDRONE to computer. Can you share the code if you completed it ??

Answer (score 0):

five minutes googling ;-) e.g. have a look at this [this](http://robohub.org/up-and-flying-with-the-ar-drone-and-ros-getting-started/)

Comment: I checked it already. I need to stream videos so it doesn't help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972143/bag-file-to-run-the-image-stream-from-ardrone-rostopic-suggestion-needed   Kindly look into this

Comment: ok sorry, than I can't help as that is the way I would go before implementing something else